# Replace "in" if prefixed by a number with double quotation "

Tags: excel, vba, string

I need to replace `"in"` if prefixed by a number with double quotation **"**.
I tried the below code, but it has not replaced anything.

| **Current** | **Expected** |
| --- | --- |
| zzz 8in zz | zzz 8" zz |
| zzz 8in. zz | zzz 8". zz |
| zzz 12in zz 6in | zzz 12" zz 6" |
| zzz 8inx10in zz | zzz 8"x10" zz |

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text

Sub Replace_Strings()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, rng As Range, arr, i As Long
   
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set rng = ws.Range("C2:C" & ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row)
    
    arr = rng.Value2

    For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
        arr(i, 1) = Replace(arr(i, 1), "#in", "#""")
    Next i

   rng.Value = arr
   
End Sub
```

Comment: Version of Excel? Will there always be a `<space>` prior to the number?

Comment: @Ron Rosenfeld I am using Excel 2016, in my fourth sample there's no space before the last number `zzz 8inx10in zz`

Comment: In that case, one of the VBA solutions should work. My personal preference would be the Regex solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a [Regular Expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/)

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Replace_Strings()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, rng As Range, c As Range
    Dim Regex As Object
    Set Regex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    With Regex
      .Global = True
      .MultiLine = False
      .IgnoreCase = True
      .Pattern = "(\d+)in"
    End With
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    With ws
        Set rng = .Range("C2:C" & .Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row)
    End With
    
    For Each c In rng
        c.Offset(, 1) = Regex.Replace(c, "$1""")
    Next
   
End Sub
```

As a Function (locate in a module)

```vb
Function Replace_Strings(s As String)

    With CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = False
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Pattern = "(\d+)in"
        Replace_Strings = .Replace(s, "$1""")
    End With
    
End Function
```

Comment: It works perfectly, Please could also add as a function?

Answer (score 1):

Plase, try the next way. Not needing iteration, I think it should be faster than `RegEx` version:

```
Sub replaceIn()
  Dim ws As Worksheet, rng As Range, lastR As Long
  
  Set ws = ActiveSheet
  lastR = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
  
  Set rng = Range("A2:A" & lastR)
  rng.Replace "in ", """ ", xlPart
  rng.Replace "inx", """x", xlPart
  rng.Replace "in. ", """. "
  rng.Replace "in", """"
  
End Sub
```

If you need the return to be done in the next column, as I can see in your question but supposing that it only serves to better understand the need, it can be adapted to do it.

Comment: [Range.Replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.replace) is a fast way. *Side note: think 2nd & 3rd OP example need further range.replaces* @FaneDuru

Comment: @T.M. Yes, I did not even test it. It looked enough... I can add other two lines, but it will not be so elegant, on my taste. In fact, I will write them. I will not choose my answer, anyhow... :)

Comment: you can hear a pin drop

Comment: With no offence, But I think you did not test your answer at all.
Before your last edit, It was replacing all strings ends with `in ` e.g Bin ,Coin .
After your last edit, It even replaces all strings contain `*in*` e.g `line`.

Comment: @Soma yes, I did not test the code, indeed. I tested each line and they work as they should. Only now I can see that the replaced range does not refresh after each step, as I thought to be the normal  behavior. I do not have time now to explore the issue. Anyhow, you've got an answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

This workaround using recursive function calls to get all matches. Select the range on the sheet where you want to apply the code.

```
Sub inchanger()

For Each cell In Selection
  cell.value = rplfind(cell.value, 1)
Next cell

End Sub

-----------------------------------

Function rplfind(ByVal txt As String, ByVal i As Long) As String

If IsError(Application.Search("?in", txt, i)) Then
Else
  j = Application.Search("?in", txt, i + 1)
  If IsError(j) Then rplfind = txt: Exit Function
    If IsNumeric(Mid(txt, j, 1)) Then
      txt = WorksheetFunction.Replace(txt, j + 1, 2, """")
      txt = rplfind(txt, j)
    End If
  End If
rplfind = txt

End Function
```